# Using infinite loops in std::thread to increment and display a value

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

Considering the following, simple code:

```
using ms = std::chrono::milliseconds;
int val = 0;
for(;;)
{
    std::cout << val++ << ' ';
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(ms(200));
}
```

We see that we infinitely print subsequent numbers each 0.2 second.

Now, I would like to implement the same logic using a helper class and multithreading. My aim is to be able to run something similar to this:

```
int main()
{
    Foo f;
    std::thread t1(&Foo::inc, f);
    std::thread t2(&Foo::dis, f);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

where `Foo::inc()` will increment a member variable `val` of an object `f` by `1` and `Foo::dis()` will display **the same** variable.

Since the original idea consisted of incrementing and printing the value infinitely, I would assume that both of those functions must contain an infinite loop. The problem that could occur is data race - reading and incrementing the very same variable. To prevent that I decided to use `std::mutex`.

My idea of implementing `Foo` is as follows:

```
class Foo {
    int val;
public:
    Foo() : val{0} {}
    void inc()
    {
        for(;;){
            mtx.lock();
            ++val;
            mtx.unlock();
        }
    }
    void dis()
    {
        using ms = std::chrono::milliseconds;
        for(;;){
            mtx.lock();
            std::cout << val << ' ';
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(ms(200));
            mtx.unlock();
        }
    }
};
```

Obviously it's missing the `mtx` object, so the line

```
std::mutex mtx;
```

is written just under the `#include`s, declaring `mtx` as a global variable.

To my understanding, combining this class' definition with the above `main()` function should issue two, separate, infinite loops that each will firstly lock the mutex, either increment or display `val` and unlock the mutex **so the other one could perform the second action**.

What actually happens is instead of displaying the sequence of `0 1 2 3 4...` it simply displays `0 0 0 0 0...`. My guess is that I am either using `std::mutex::lock` and `std::mutex::unlock` incorrectly, or my fundamental understanding of multithreading is lacking some basic knowledge.

The question is - **where is my logic wrong?**

- How would I approach this problem using a helper class and two `std::thread`s with member functions of the same object?
- Is there a guarantee that the incrementation of `val` and printing of it will each occur one after the other using this kind of logic? i.e. will there never be a situation when `val` is incremented twice before it being displayed, or vice versa?

Comment: How are you launching the threads?

Comment: I have included the `main()` function where I create the two thread objects with mentioned member functions, if that is what you are asking about. If not, please specify since my english is not the greatest

Comment: why aren't you using `std::atomic<int>`?

Comment: What advantages does it have over `std::mutex` lock in this particular problem?

Answer (score 2):

A mutex is not a signal.  It is not fair.  You can unlock then relock a mutex, and someone waiting for it can never notice.

All it guarantees is that exactly one thread has it locked.

Your task, splitting it into two threads, seems utterly pointless.  Using sleep for is also a bad idea, as printing takes an unknown amount of time, making the period between displays drift by an unpredictable amount.

You probably (A) do not want to do this, and failing that (B) use a condition variable.  One thread increments the value every X time (based off a fixed start time, not based off delays of X), and then signs the condition variable.  It holds no mutex while waiting.

The other thread waits on the condition variable and the counter value changing.  When it wakes, it copies the counter, unlocks, prints once, updates the last value seen, then waits on the condition variable (and value changing) again.

A mild benefit to this is that if the io is ridiculously slow or blocking, the counter keeps incrementing, so other consumers can use it.

```
struct Counting {
  int val = -1; // optionally atomic
  std::mutex mtx;
  std::condition_variable cv;

  void counting() {
    while(true){
      {
        auto l=std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mtx);
        ++val; // even if atomic, val must be modified while or before the mtx is held and before the notify.
      }
      // or notify all:
      cv.notify_one(); // no need to hold lock here
      using namespace std::literals;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms); // ideally wait to an absolute time instead of delay here
    }
  }

  void printing() {
    int old_val=-1;
    while(true){
      int new_val=[&]{
        auto lock=std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mtx);

        cv.wait(lock, [&]{ return val!=old_val; }); // only print if we have a new value
        return val;
      }();// release lock, no need to hold it while printing

      std::cout << new_val << std::endl; // endl flushes.  Note there are threading issues streaming to cout like this.
      old_val=new_val; // update last printed value
    }
  }
};
```

if one thread is printing the other counting, you'll get basically what you want.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the meaning of locking and unlocking `std::mutex`. The task itself was not meant to be meaningful, it was simply an exercise to practice multithreading from a very basic perspective. Could you please provide some sample code for the idea of condition variable, working every X time and "*copying the counter, unlocking, printing once, updating the last value seen [...]*"?

Comment: @Fureeishf: I agree with yakk. Also for an exercise, the problem  remains that a mutex isn't fair.  That is no problem if both threads are doing useful work, but here neither counting nor printing  is useful in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

You are sleeping with the thread locked preventing the other thread from running for most of the time.

```
void dis()
{
    using ms = std::chrono::milliseconds;
    for(;;){
        mtx.lock();
        std::cout << val << ' ';
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(ms(200)); // this is still blocking the other thread
        mtx.unlock();
    }
}
```

Try this:

```
void dis()
{
    using ms = std::chrono::milliseconds;
    for(;;){
        mtx.lock();
        std::cout << val << ' ';
        mtx.unlock(); // unlock to allow the other thread to progress
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(ms(200));
    }
}
```

Also, rather than using a global `std::mutex` you could add it as a *member* of your class.

If you want to synchronize the threads to produce an even output of numbers incrementing by exactly one each time then you need something like a [std::condition_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) so that each thread can signal the other when it has done it's part of the job (thread one - *incrementing* and thread 2 - *printing*).

Here is an example:

```
class Foo {
    int val;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool new_value; // flag when a new value is ready

public:
    Foo() : val{0}, new_value{false} {}

    void inc()
    {
        for(;;){
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

            // release the lock and wait until new_value has been consumed
            cv.wait(lock, [this]{ return !new_value; }); // wait for change in new_value

            ++val;
            new_value = true; // signal for the other thread there is a new value

            cv.notify_one(); // wake up the other thread
        }
    }

    void dis()
    {
        using ms = std::chrono::milliseconds;
        for(;;){
            // a nice delay
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(ms(200));

            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

            // release the lock and wait until new_value has been produced
            cv.wait(lock, [this]{ return new_value; }); // wait for a new value

            std::cout << val << ' ' << std::flush; // don't forget to flush
            new_value = false; // signal for the other thread that the new value was used

            cv.notify_one(); // wake up the other thread
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Foo f;

    std::thread t1(&Foo::inc, &f);
    std::thread t2(&Foo::dis, &f);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: While this, combined with @user2308211's hint on passing the address of an object rather than the object itself, displays incrementing values, it omits most of them. I was specifically aiming for achieving the same result as the original `for` loop in my question

Comment: @Fureeish You have two independently running loops. They are not going to synchronize what they do unless you put in the code to make that happen. Typically you might use a `std::condition_variable` that lets each thread signal to the other thread when it has done it's particular job.

Comment: @Fureeish I added an example using a *condition variable* that should do what you want.

Comment: Copy val when you print it, then test val does not equal the last value printed.  Get rid of the bool and the incrementing thread waiting.

Comment: @Yakk That was my original thought but then this is just an example problem. The real principle, I think, is getting each thread to do one operation in turn in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

When launching a thread with a member function, you need to pass the address of the object, not the object itself

```
std::thread t2(&Foo::dis, &f);
```

Please note that this still won't print 1 2 3 4 .. You'll need to have the increment operation and the print alternate exactly for that.

```
#include <thread>
#include<iostream>
#include <mutex>
std::mutex mtx1, mtx2;

class Foo {
    int val;
public:
    Foo() : val{0} { mtx2.lock(); }
    void inc()
    {
        for(;;){
            mtx1.lock();
            ++val;
            mtx2.unlock();
        }
    }
    void dis()
    {
        using ms = std::chrono::milliseconds;
        for(;;){
            mtx2.lock();
            std::cout << val <<std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(ms(200));
            mtx1.unlock();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    std::thread t1(&Foo::inc, &f);
    std::thread t2(&Foo::dis, &f);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Also take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: Great point on passing the address of an object. Could you please elaborate a little more on the usage of two `mutex` objects? Can I think about this as a way of communicating which action can be performed next and which one cannot?

Comment: I tend to think that way, but I think the condition_variable approach is the better way of doing that. The code above is just functionally correct.